# Cannot find javahl, svnkit nor command line svn client

Tags: svn, ant

I've done numerous svn / ant set-ups and but this time cann't figure out what's wrong.

Using Linux,

```
svn 1.6.6
ant 1.8.2
svnant 1.3.1
```

I've copied the svnant jar files into `$ANT_HOME/lib`

```
top@secret:~/apps/apache-ant-1.8.2/lib$ ls -l
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  244831 2011-06-23 07:55 ganymed.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  948100 2011-06-23 07:55 jna.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   76383 2011-06-23 07:55 svnant.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  215757 2011-06-23 07:55 svnClientAdapter.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   89412 2011-06-23 07:55 svnjavahl.jar
```

etc...

My build file specifies:

```
<taskdef name="svn" classname="org.tigris.subversion.svnant.SvnTask"   />
```

But whenever I execute

```
   <target name="update">
                <svn>
                        <update dir="."/>
                </svn>
        </target>
```

I get the dreaded:

```
update:
      [svn] Missing 'javahl' dependencies on the classpath !

BUILD FAILED
/home/top/apps/utils/build.xml:26: Cannot find javahl, svnkit nor command line svn client
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

I assumed copying the svnant jars into $ANT_HOME/lib should be enough?

Comment: this is a crosspost from http://serverfault.com/questions/283373/cannot-find-javahl-svnkit-nor-command-line-svn-client

Comment: As of svnant 1.3.2 the attributes svnkit and javahl have been deprecated. The alternative is to use the svnSetting task. See my answer below.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Javahl way always needs some kind of os-dependent driver. This is mostly hard to set-up and I don't recommend using it.

You should try using `svnkit`:

```
<svn svnkit="true">
```

This uses the pure java library, but needs `svnkit.jar` to be in the classpath.

#### References:

1. http://subclipse.tigris.org/svnant/svn.html
2. http://subclipse.tigris.org/wiki/JavaHL

I only use the fallback/commandline version, where the svn executable is in the PATH. This works in most cases without problems with the following settings:

```
<svn svnkit="false" javahl="false">
```

**Note:** These settings are for svnant 1.31 and prior. Since version 1.32 you can use `<svnSetting />`, which is described in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10483758/644450)

Comment: The strange thing is I've always done it as per my question before i.e. bung all the jars into $ANT_HOME/lib. I've no idea what's different this time. Maybe it's something to do with the fact that I'm using svn 1.6 instead of 1.5, and svnant 1.3 instead of 1.2

Comment: It could be that the new version of svn ant behaves differently. I only vagueley remember the last struggle with it and I think I had similar problems.

Comment: As of svnant 1.3.2 the attributes svnkit and javahl have been deprecated. The alternative is to use the svnSetting task. See my answer below.

Comment: Funny thing is that the 1.3.2 Version of SVN-ANT is not available for download. I suggest using jars from latest SVNkit to get this to work.

Answer (score 15):

As of `svnant 1.3.2` the attributes `svnkit` and `javahl` have been deprecated. The alternative is to use the `svnSetting` task.

Put this task in your build file somewhere:

```
<svnSetting
    svnkit="false"
    javahl="false"
    id="svn.settings"/>
```

Then when you are calling the `svn` task use it this way (take note of the `refid` attribute):

```
<target name="doingSomethingAwesome">
    <svn refid="svn.settings">
        <!-- do something -->
    </svn>
</target>
```

Hope this helps, did me.

[REFERENCE](http://subclipse.tigris.org/svnant/svntask.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting "Cannot find javahl, svnkit nor command line svn client"
then you have to make ensure that svn path have been set or not :
for exa : path=c:\svn\bin;

Comment: OP is using GNU/Linux