# svnant failing when trying to tag

Tags: ant, svnant

I want create an ant build that creates a reference tag to a given project, but I'm getting an error:

```
Cannot find javahl, svnkit nor command line svn client
```

My build.xml:

```
<property name="tag.name" value="...." />
<path id="path.svnant">
    <pathelement location="${basedir}/svnant.jar" />
    <pathelement location="${basedir}/svnClientAdapter.jar" />
</path>
<typedef resource="org/tigris/subversion/svnant/svnantlib.xml" classpathref="..." />

<path id="svnant.classpath">
    <fileset dir="${svnant.lib.dir}">
        <include name="**/*.jar" />
    </fileset>
</path>

<target name="svntag" description="tags individual project using svnant task">
    <property name="svn.tag.message" value="Tagging Project ${project.name} with tag name ${tag.name} from trunk " />
    <property name="src.url" value="${svn.base.url}/${project.name}/trunk/" />
    <property name="dest.url" value="${svn.base.url}/${project.name}/tags/${tag.name}" />
    <echo message="${svn.project.base.path}" />
    <echo message="${svn.tag.message}" />
    <echo message="${src.url}" />
    <echo message="${dest.url}" />
         <svnSetting javahl="false" svnkit="true" username="...." password="...." id="svn.settings" />
    <svn>
        <copy srcUrl="${src.url}" destUrl="${dest.url}" message="${svn.tag.message}" />
    </svn>   
</target>
```

Answer (score 0):

See another question for details [Cannot find javahl, svnkit nor command line svn client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6457457/cannot-find-javahl-svnkit-nor-command-line-svn-client)

I recommend you to use SVNKit (http://svnkit.com/kb/user-guide-svnant.html) because it's pure java SVN implementation so can be run on platforms where java exists.

Comment: I tried to use svkit, as I explained in the link I've been through, but it keeps giving me the same error...

Comment: Put jars "svnkit.jar" and "svnjavahl.jar" into ANT_HOME/lib directory. Add also <svn refid="svn.settings">. I could work with svn after this.