# Cannot use javahl, JavaSVN nor command line svn client

Tags: svn, ant

I have my build.xml contain following entries(Note jars are present at this locations).

```
<path id="svnant.classpath">
      <fileset dir="${basedir}/antlib">
        <include name="svnant.jar"/>
        <include name="svnClientAdapter.jar"/>
      </fileset>
 </path>

  <!-- Load the SVN task library -->
  <taskdef resource="org/tigris/subversion/svnant/svnantlib.xml" uri="antlib:org.tigris.subversion.svnant" classpathref="svnant.classpath"/>
```

Following entry causing the above mentioned exception

```
<svnant:svn javahl="false">
   <revert dir="${runtimeDir}" recurse="true"/>
</svnant:svn>
```

Version Info of my setup

- Ant version : 1.7.0
- Java version : 1.6
- SvnAnt : (don't know version)

I went through the solution available on the Internet but still I am not able to solve this problem.Please help me out with this.

Comment: See [Cannot find javahl, svnkit nor command line svn client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6457457/cannot-find-javahl-svnkit-nor-command-line-svn-client).

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the [SlikSVN](https://sliksvn.com/pub/) Client and it solved the problem. After downloading make sure that environment variable **Path** is updated and contains the entry for **{SlikSvn_Home}/bin** . One thing to note that SlikSVN version has to be compatible with the SVN that we have installed on our machine.